# Writing csv file with CSV.jl throws StackOverflowError message

Tags: dataframe, csv, julia

`CSV.write()` returns: `ERROR: LoadError: StackOverflowError:` further down claiming `--- the last 2 lines are repeated 39990 more times ---`. Which is nonsense since the data frame to be written is acknowledged to be of 129x6 dimension with no empty fields. I fear the function is counting rows beyond the dimension of the data frame and shouldn't be doing so. How do I make this function work?

```
using CSV,DataFrames
file=DataFrame(
        a=1:50,
        b=1:50,
        c=Vector{Any}(missing,50),
        d=Vector{Any}(missing,50))
CSV.write("a.csv",file)
file=CSV.read("a.csv",DataFrame)
c,d=[],[]
for i in 1:nrow(file)
    push!(c,file.a[i]*file.b[i])
    push!(d,file.a[i]*file.b[i]/file.a[i])
end
file[!,:c]=c
file[!,:d]=d
# I found no straight forward way to fill empty columns based on the values of filled columns in a for loop that wouldn't generate error messages
CSV.write("a.csv",DataFrame) # Error in question here
```

Comment: Can you please share a code example? Minimal reproduction

Comment: A MWE (minimal working example) of the error will help a lot. In essence, if you can, try to remove as much of the DataFrame as possible while still getting error (`deleteat!(df, [2, 3])` deletes rows 2,3)

Comment: "the last 2 lines are repeated 39990 more times" refers to 2 lines of the Stacktrace, not rows of the DataFrame. It means that two functions are calling each other about 40000 times, and the Stacktrace is abbreviating that into this message. That must be the reason for the Stackoverfow too.  Are there any nested data structures in your DataFrame? Showing us the full stacktrace will also help a lot with finding which functions are recursively calling each other and why.

Comment: @SundarR Error is output at the end of a script. In the beginning of the script I open the file then fill two columns of only missing values via a `for` loop looping through the values of other columns to calculate the new ones (the way one would do in Excel). I will attempt to reproduce the error with a minimal example, if I can.

Comment: A minimal example will surely help, but meanwhile showing the existing error message in full will also help. The question says "ERROR: LoadError: StackOverflowError: further down claiming --- the last 2 lines are repeated 39990 more times ---" showing the parts in between these two (and the rest of the error output too) will give more info about what's going on.

Comment: @SundarR I provided the example and as I did I figured out what the problem seemed to be. I mistakenly typed `CSV.write("a.csv",DataFrame)` instead of `CSV.write("a.csv",file)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StackOverflowError is indeed due to the line

```
CSV.write("a.csv",DataFrame)
```

which tries to write the data type itself to a file instead of the actual dataframe variable. (The reason that leads to this particular error is an implementation detail that's described [here](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/issues/3199).)

> `# I found no straight forward way to fill empty columns based on the values of filled columns in a for loop that wouldn't generate error messages`

You don't need a `for` loop for this, just

```
file.c = file.a .* file.b
file.d = file.a .* file.b ./ file.a
```

will do the job. (Though I don't understand the point of the `file.d` calculation - maybe this is just a sample dummy calculation you chose just for illustration.)